# On importing Contacts, I can't match their Organization to the Employer field in CiviCRM

Tags: import, relationships, organization

I have imported a new batch of Organizations. I want to import additional Contacts and match their Organization name in the .csv with the Employer field in CiviCRM. I don't see "Employer" as an option for matching fields.  I looked all the way down at the bottom of the list of fields and didn't see anything that would help in setting up the relationship.  What am I missing

CiviCRM 5.45.0.on WordPress Version 5.9.2

Comment: Towards the bottom of the right column headed 'Matching CiviCRM field' there is the option '-related  contact info'. Select that and then scroll down to see the relationships.

Comment: I found and selected '-related contact info' but I don't see any scroll down list where I can see relationships. All the default Relationships are enabled.

Comment: Underneath ''-related contact info' is the list of relationships you can choose,  They are the last in the list of 'Matching CiviCRM Field' field names,

Comment: Thank you for your persevering. I was looking for a 2nd drop-down menu.

Comment: It would help to flag the answer as correct (if it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the step where you match input fields to CiviCRM fields, look in the right hand column for '-related contact info'. Underneath that is the list of relationships you can choose. This set of fields are the last in the list of 'Matching CiviCRM Field' field names.